# Multiple parameters PUT - NodeJS - No ORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I've made some API (NodeJS, db: PostgreSQL) for my Android app and now I'm facing problem with PUT. Ofc, API isn't anything special and it's made with express template, without ORM. I'm not backend dev, but I had to do that. But what is my problem... I've tried multiple times to make route, that allows me to pass 3 arguments. First one is ID (protege_patron), second is firstname (from input) and last one is lastname (from input).

```
router.put('/:firstname/:lastname', (req, res, next) => {

    const protege_firstname = req.params.firstname
    const protege_lastname = req.params.lastname

    const { protege_patron } = req.body

    pool.query(
      'UPDATE proteges SET protege_patron = $1 WHERE (protege_firstname = $2 AND protege_lastname = $3)',
      [protege_patron, protege_firstname, protege_lastname],
      (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          throw error
        }
        res.status(200).send(`User modified with ID: ${id}`)
      }
    )
})
```

I guess my problem is `router.put('/:firstname/:lastname'`, but I just can't find any solution or anything that would help me. Most of examples use ORM or other stuff. Is there any solution, link to some hidden knowledge, anything? I know my code is... bad, still.

Comment: Whats the problem above code?? Whether you can't get the `params`??

Comment: Yea, I guess. Atm I can't even curl data. My question is mostly, what should I change that would work if I would make PUT request at url for example ```localhost:3000/proteges/Mike/Smith```... Or should I just go for ```localhost:3000/proteges/1``` and then inside swap data, protege_patron as ID and rest as body. I'm really bad at backend. You can downvote me. Question is, is there anything wrong with that code above? Or how can I curl that? I just can't test that atm.

Comment: why do you need those 3 pieces of information? If this is a REST api then the `.put()` code should just be the `:id` param, with the other two values being passed through the `req.body`.

Comment: I have one activity in Android Studio, that signs "protege" to "patron" and one global ID (based on user logged). I've thought that it would be nice if I could put fIrstname and lastname in one input (then split it) and then change id of protege with such firstname and lastname. I know about this ```:id``` only way, sadly I can't see that working in my app.
Or maybe, if I would use GET before and based on that check if user exists, and if he exists, I would take his ID and then pass it through PUT... Anyway, that would make me do GET with 2 params...

Comment: absolutely correct@Jhecht. Go with this way and maintain this way for future maintenance.